# I am unable to write my signature using the trackpad in Preview.app

Tags: macos, preview, trackpad, bug, digital-signature

I click on the signature button in the Preview.app toolbar:

[image]

The following box pops up:

[image]

I click on the <kbd>Click Here To Begin</kbd> button. The box is now ready for input:

[image]

However, I cannot get any markings at all to show up as my signature. My box always looks like the above image.

I've tried doing the above in an image document and a PDF document. I've tried holding down the trackpad while writing and not holding the trackpad down while writing. I've tried using a mouse.

Is there a fix for this bug, so that I can use my Macbook trackpad to write my signature?

Note: the Camera-based signature method technically works on my machine. However, its rendition ability isn't great.

---

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

---

Comment: I know that I can create my signature in any number of other applications, so this bug is not a huge issue. I thought that I would make this post because I couldn't find a post about this bug online.

Comment: Ever find a solution? I'm having a similar problem, only with the "Camera" option.

Comment: Apparently some bug in Preview.app, happens even in High Sierra 10.13.4. Closing all open documents and relaunching Preview.app should fix the problem.

Comment: The camera option worked fine for me. I'm running Htgh Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: @rubik'ssphere ever found a solution? facing the same issue with MacOS Sierra 10.14.3

Comment: @zerohedge I just tried it, and the feature happened to work properly. I'm still on 10.11.6. I have no idea why it sometimes works and, other times, does not.

Comment: Giving "input Monitoring" permissions to Preview fixes the problem.
Go To System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy and add it in the Input Monitoring list.

[ MacOS BigSur 11.6 ]

Comment: Might be a hardware issue, on my Big Sur trackpad handwriting has not been working for more than a year now (not for signature creation, not as handwriting input source, nothing).

Comment: @Hammond95 's comment gave me hope, but didn't work in macOS 13. Might still be necessary. I remember reading something about document requirements, not just their permissions. Gotta look if i find it, again.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across getting it working for the first time ever. I've tried using it several times with no success. What was different this time, was while the signature window was active but I hadn't yet clicked "Click here to begin", 
I accidentally clicked the 'text entry' tool that creates a textbox with default red ink. While that was active and accepting input, I then clicked "Click here to begin", and to my surprise it registered my trackpad signature.

Since I couldn't press a key to end the drawing (since the text box was still active and typing my keypresses), I canceled, exited textbox entry, and tried to register a signature again. This time it also worked.

Comment: Wow this worked, I had to reread your solution, it is actually very important for the red textbox to be selected and highlighted, which is more difficult to happen by accident than simply clicking the create text button.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you do that, the signature dialog disappears. At least at macOS 13. Can't confirm for earlier versions anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on 10.13.3 High Sierra.  Rebooting the computer fixed the issue.

Comment: Sadly, a reboot (or 100) most definitely does not fix the issue on 10.11.6.